# Jekyll - data files and structured YAML

Tags: yaml, jekyll, itunes, github-pages, podcast

I'm using a Jekyll template for podcast site and RSS,  including iTunes info. Now, my `podcast.yml` file is like this :

```
name: "Fate Masters" 
gpluspage: "https://plus.google.com/communities/100913016060492249875" 
copyright: (CC BY-NC-SA) 2015 - Fate Masters 
language: pt-br 
podcast_links: 
    - format: MP3 
      link: http://feeds.feedburner.com/FateMastersRPG 
    - format: OGG 
      link: http://feeds.feedburner.com/FateMastersRPG-OGG 
 itunes-explicit: "NO" 
 itunes-keywords: "RPG, Fate, Fate Básico, Mestre, Narrador" 
 itunes-podcast_image: /images/FateMasters.jpg 
 itunes-author: "Fate Masters" 
 itunes-email: fabiocosta0305@gmail.com 
 itunes-categories: 
     - RPG 
     - Fate 
     - Fate Core 
     - Fate Básico
```

However... See all those `itunes-*` tags...  I like to put this as  an `itunes` structured info with pairs like  - categories and so... But I can't do this, because using `site.podcast.itunes.copyright` would return nothing...

Any tips

Comment: 'podcast.yml' is a _data file or a collection ?

Comment: It's a file at _data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your file is a data file, you will have to put all you podcasts in this same file.

In order to do this, you will have to reformat a little :

```
- name: "Fate Masters"
  gpluspage: "https://plus.google.com/communities/100913016060492249875"
  copyright: (CC BY-NC-SA) 2015 - Fate Masters
  language: pt-br
  podcast_links:
    - format: MP3
      link: http://feeds.feedburner.com/FateMastersRPG
    - format: OGG
      link: http://feeds.feedburner.com/FateMastersRPG-OGG
  itunes:
    explicit: "NO"
    keywords: "RPG, Fate, Fate Básico, Mestre, Narrador"
    podcast_image: /images/FateMasters.jpg
    author: "Fate Masters"
    email: fabiocosta0305@gmail.com
    categories:
     - RPG
     - Fate
     - Fate Core
     - Fate Básico

- name: "other"
  copyright: MIT
```

Then you can loop over podcasts like this :

```
{% for p in site.data.podcast %}
<h2>{{ p.name }}</h2>
<p>{{ p.copyright }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip... But what I want is to turn to put all that `itunes-*` info into an `itunes` structure

Comment: You than have to reformat your yml. I've edited my answer with itunes info under itunes key.

Comment: Thanks... I'll try this